# How to control zero window probes and retransmissions in python socket?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming, handshake

In some cases, the client peer sets window size to zero in TCP handshake, and if you want to send some data, then the socket is out of control: you can't even close it because it will continue sending zero window probe.

In another case, the client peer will reply nothing to your request, so python socket begins to do retransmissions again and again.

I known there are many option flags to help control the time and account, but I find little support in python. You can find nothing to control zero window probes and retransmissions.

Could anybody tell me the ways to solve this problem?

Here is a picture of python socket TCP option flags:
[python socket TCP option flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwLJq.png)

Comment: I don't know what you meen by "can't even close it".  You can always go nonblocking or interrupt your write with a signal.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try nonblocking. But I don`t understand how to interrupt it with a signal using python code.

Comment: If you don't want to use a signal, use nonblocking IO.

Comment: I am very disappointed to find that python surpports little option flags to  control zero window probes and retransmissions.

Comment: It's going to support the same options that other languages support. Python uses the same API as C, after all.